# Deedle Row based calculation

Tags: f#, deedle

I am trying to use Deedle to do some row based calculation. however most of the examples are column based. For example I have this simple structure:

```
let tt = Series.ofObservations[ 1=>10.0; 3=>20.0;5=> 30.0 ]
let tt2 = Series.ofObservations[1=> 10.0; 3=> Double.NaN; 6=>30.0 ]
let f1 = frame ["cola" => tt; "colb"=>tt2]

 val f1 : Frame<int,string> =
          cola      colb      
      1 -> 10        10        
      3 -> 20        <missing> 
      5 -> 30        <missing> 
      6 -> <missing> 30
```

I want to calculate the mean of cola and colb. if I do

```
f1.Rows |> Series.mapValues(fun r -> (r.GetAs<float>("cola") + r.GetAs<float>("colb") )/2.0)
val it : Series<int,float> =
     1 -> 10        
     3 -> <missing> 
     5 -> <missing> 
     6 -> <missing>
```

i know i can match with each column to handle the mean, however this will not be practical if there are lots of columns.

each row returned by f1.Rows is a ObjectSeries can this be converted into a float Series and apply the stats.mean to a row?

thanks 
casbby

**Update:**

I think i might have found one of the ways to do this (reference: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/issues/100) :

folding operation:

```
 f1.Rows |> Series.mapValues(fun v -> v.As<float>() |> Series.foldValues (fun acc elem -> elem + acc) 0.0 )
```

mean (it properly skip the missing value):

```
 f1.Rows |> Series.mapValues(fun v -> v.As<float>() |> Stats.mean )
```

count:

```
 f1.Rows |> Series.mapValues(fun v -> v.As<float>() |> Stats.count )
```

if there is a different way please let me know. hopefully this can be useful to new comers like myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach using `f1.Rows`, casting each row to a numerical series and then applying `Stats` functions is exactly what I was going to suggest as an answer, so I think that approach makes a perfect sense.

Another option that I can think of is to turn the frame into a de-normalized representation and then group the rows by the `cola` and `colb` values (so, you'll have all data as rows, but grouped by the other attribute):

```
let byCol = 
  f1
  |> Frame.stack
  |> Frame.groupRowsByString "Column";;
```

This gives you:

```
          Row Column Value 
cola 0 -> 1   cola   10    
     2 -> 3   cola   20    
     3 -> 5   cola   30    
colb 1 -> 1   colb   10    
     4 -> 6   colb   30
```

Now you can use functions working with hierarchical indices to do the calculations. For example, to compute mean of `Value` for the two groups, you can write:

```
byCol?Value |> Stats.levelMean fst
```

I'm not sure which approach I'd recommend at the moment - it probably depends on other operations that you need to do with the data. But it's good to keep the alternative one in mind..

Comment: Thank you for the advice and support. I didnt know about the stack function at all. The more I use Deedle the more I realise I might have missed something in the API. it is such a comprehensive package.